# python3 for loop dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [whats another way to write python3 zip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371279/whats-another-way-to-write-python3-zip)

whats a better way to write these things I was introduced to these codes but I am not used to seeing them these ways:

```
(alla,allc,) = (set(s) for s in zip(*animaldictionary.keys()))
```

how else can you write this

```
print('\n'.join(['\t'.join((c,str(sum(animaldictionary.get(ac,0) 
for a in alla 
     for ac in ((a,c,),))//12)))
             for c in sorted(allc)]))
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly the same question that you asked previously [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371279/whats-another-way-to-write-python3-zip) (and which I answered at great length). There's no need to ask it again!

Answer (score 1):

I'll update my answer with a more comprehensive (no pun intended) result once I get home and have more time to wrap my head around this interesting set of comprehensions.  For now you will want to check out the following:

- [List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tut-listcomps)
- [Nested List Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions)
- [Sets And Set Comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)